# Is Keiko Numata's backstory the same in the anime as it is in the the novel?

Tags: another

In the novel, it says that Keiko Numata became an insane crone murderer due to Ikuo's death. However, she commits suicide by biting off her tongue in the novel, while in the anime she is stopped by Chibiki and she is seen to have stab wounds in her back.

I am wondering if her backstory (going insane and all) is the same as it is in the novel - or did something else happen in the anime which relates to her stab wounds?

Answer (score -1):

It would be fair to assume that her background is generally the same. All events leading up to and beyond the point you are referring to suggest the same woeful tale. Maybe it was an accident that occurred in one of her insane fits, or maybe they are scars of a previous attempt to contain her.

One thing is for certain, if you don't want to live anymore, and you want to make a very big mess, bite off your tongue.